# how i can insert a javascript code inside visual web jsf page in netbeans?

Tags: javascript, netbeans

how  i can insert a javascript code inside visual web jsf page in netbeans 6.5.1 ?

```
<webuijsf:head  id="head1"> <script type="text/javascript" src="ddaccordion.js"></script> </weuijsf:head>
```

it doesn't work however it works fine inside dreamweaver or visual studio 
so i tried to make an html file and write this code inside it and link it to jsf file also it doesn't work

```
 <head> <script type="text/javascript" src="ddaccordion.js"> </script> </head>
```

so any help pls

Answer (score 0):

Put `<script...>` in the `<h:head>` tag:

```
<h:head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="ddaccordion.js"> </script>
</h:head>
```